# adding propertyname and values

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function, object

Write a function that takes items object,  propertyName and value as parameters.
The propertyName is added to each Object.
Try not to mutate the original object.

```
const items = {
    item_392019302: {
        name: "Washing Machine",
        stock: 3,
    },
    item_392019342: {
        name: "Light Bulb",
        stock: 3,
    },
    item_392019340: {
        name: "Streaming Device",
        stock: 2
    },
    item_392019389: {
        name: "Plug",
        stock: 1
    },
    item_392019311: {
        name: "Trace",
        stock: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please verify that items is array or object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `...` spread operator to make a shallow copy of the object so that you don't have to mutate the `items` object

for example

```
function foo (items, thingToAdd){
  return {...items, ...thingToAdd};
}
```